# Error in XAMPP "cannot calculate MAC address: exit status 1"

Tags: xampp

I just installed XAMPP-VM on my mac, and i'm having a problem when I clicked start it shows error

> cannot calculate MAC address: exit status 1

could someone explain what this error means and how to fix it?

I'm using MacOS 10.15 Catalina and XAMPP-VM ver 7.4.7   [image]